# Определить состоит ли строка из набора других строк

Tags: строки

Есть длинная строка без пробелов (текст) и несколько строк короче (допустимые слова). Нужно по длинной строке и набору допустимых слов определить, можно ли разбить текст на отдельные слова из набора. Сначала сделал так: отсортировал допустимые слова по длине и начал убирать из исходной строки все вхождения. Потом следующую и тд. Но нет. Не работает. В какую сторону еще подумать?

Comment: Текст состоит только из данных слов, или могут быть ещё символы? Т.е.  "катя", "васю" подходит под "катялюбитвасю"?

Comment: @MBo
может состоять из любых символов, задача как раз и состоит в том, можно ли разбить текст на эти слова. ПРи этом каждое слово может встречаться несколько раз в тексте, а может и не встречаться вовсе. То есть например: 

катялюбитивасюипетю
катя
васю
любит
и
петю

Ответ да. 

а например 
катялюбитвасюиюру
катя
любит
васю
и

Ответ нет

Comment: Дело в том, что семантически "разбить" означает, что строка должна состоять только из данных слов, и ничего более. Кроме того, есть и более сложные случаи - "воваля" включает вова и валя, но разбить вроде как нельзя. Поэтому хорошо бы увидеть точную формулировку задачи.

Comment: @MBo 
Более формально: дан текст T и набор строк s1, ... ,sn. Надо определить, представим ли T как sk1sk2...skr, где где ki — индексы строк. Индексы могут повторяться. Строка si может встречаться в разбиении текста T произвольное число раз. Можно использовать не все строки для разбиения. Строки могут идти в любом порядке.